# how to get google calender events between two dates from google API v3?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-api-client, google-oauth-java-client

I am developing calander interface and need to include google events in the calander.

I am able to list events by querying

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events
```

But, need to fetch events between two dates. I have found similar problem on 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597634/all-event-listing-on-specified-date-in-google-calender-api-v3-in-java) question but he is using javascript client, and I am not.
he is using `.setTimeMin()` method to set date.

I need to know what parameters should be passed to retrive evetns between two dates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the hint from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531081/bad-startmin-startmax-on-get-google-calendar-entries-google-api-java-client)

The parameters are `timeMin` & `timeMax` , should be passed with query string like this

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?timeMin=2012-09-30T09:11:13.562Z&timeMax=2012-10-30T09:11:13.562Z
```